# Selecting implementations of C++ functions using the linker

Tags: c++, linker, ld

I would like to test C++ functions in a piece of code by swapping them
one by one for ones that are known to work in a working context, where the swapping is done using the linker.  (I use C++ with GCC under linux.)  Unfortunately I do not know enough about how to drive the linker to know how to do this or even if it is possible.

For me, the main reason is to test students' code against a teacher's
model solution, though I can imagine plenty of other cases where such
methods may be of interest.  Note that the students' source code is
available and can be compiled in any way I like, but this source
cannot be edited.  However, the teacher's code can be modified as
needed.

There follows a simple example that shows the idea.

Here is, the teacher's code, in which the functions can call each
other in ways similar to that shown.  All functions here are assumed
to meet their specifications exactly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// model teacher program : main calls g which calls f

int f(int x) {
  cout << "in teacher-f(" << x << ")" << endl;
  return 46;
}

int g(int x) {
  cout << "in teacher-g(" << x << ")" << endl;
  int y = f(x);
  cout << "f(" << x << ") returned " << y << endl;  
  return 91;  
}

int main() {
  cout << "in teacher-main()" << endl;
  int x = 2;
  int y = g(x);
  cout << "g(" << x << ") returned " << y <<  endl;  
}
```

A typical student's code, attempting to meet the same specifications,
to be tested.  In my case a "main", several #includes, and "using
namespace std;" would be expected.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// model student program : main calls g which calls f

int f(int x) {
  cout << "in student-f(" << x << ")" << endl;
  return 27;
}

int g(int x) {
  cout << "in student-g(" << x << ")" << endl;
  int y = f(x);
  cout << "f(" << x << ") returned " << y << endl;  
  return 82;  
}

int main() {
  cout << "in student-main()" << endl;
  int x = 4;
  int y = g(x);
  cout << "g(" << x << ") returned " << y <<  endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

I want to swap each of the teacher's functions one by one to test each
student function individually.

Here is one attempt, in this case testing the student's g()

```
g++ -c student.cpp
# (this makes student.o)
# strip f() and main() from student.o:
strip -N main -N _Z1fi student.o

# similarly for teacher, but stripping g
g++ -c teacher.cpp
strip -N _Z1gi teacher.o
g++ -o final teacher.o student.o
./final
```

and the result I would expect is

```
in teacher-main()
in student-g(2)
in teacher-f(2)
f(2) returned 46
g(4) returned 82
```

unfortunately, I get:

```
strip: not stripping symbol `_Z1fi' because it is named in a relocation
```

I have tried doing something similar with .so libraries instead.  The
error message to strip disappears, but unfortunately this time the
teacher main calls the teacher g that I had tried to remove.

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o student.so student.cpp
g++ -shared -fPIC -o teacher.so teacher.cpp 
strip -N main -N _Z1fi student.so
strip -N _Z1gi  teacher.so
g++ -o final teacher.so student.so
./final
```

giving

```
in teacher-main()
in teacher-g(2)
in teacher-f(2)
f(2) returned 46
g(2) returned 91
```

Any suggestions?  Is this even possible?  If not, is there any way
round to do the same thing?  As said I cannot edit student.cpp, but I
could #include it from other source code.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: What about capturing the output of the teacher and student programs separately and comparing them with a tool like `diff` or `meld`(graphical)?

Comment: That doesn't do what I am asking for. I want to test the result of the student's g() when it calls the teachers f().  In a learning environment I want to be able to give a student credit for correctly coding g() even though his/her f() is incorrect.

Comment: Is there any reason why students need to code `main` in their file? Can you ask them to code only `f` and `g`, and then link yourself with relevant teacher's `main`? Or at least require them to submit _two_ files, one with `f` and `g`, and the other with `main`.

Comment: "unfortunately this time the teacher main calls the teacher g that I had tried to remove."
Are you sure that this is not a problem of inlining?

Comment: It is certainly possible to **ask** the students to do their coding in a particular way.  In my class they are all raw beginners and anything but the very simplest instructions will be misunderstood and ignored by a large proportion of them, leading to a large amount of teacher time being required to manually edit the student programs so they comply.   It is difficult enough to emphasise their functions have to be called f and g and not "myf" and "myg" and that if the specification says "int" then "double" will not do.

Comment: Stripping the source code of its `main` like 99+% of the time sounds simple enough with a regex. It's not like students will write stuff like `std::type_identity<int>::type main(std::void_t<decltype(42)>)`.

Comment: Good point, but I just tried it again with all functions declared with __attribute__ ((noinline)) and got the same result, so it's a linker issue not inlining.

Comment: Passer by: that is the sort of thing I have been doing up to now.  It's more than just stripping main though, because function calls to student's f() have to be changed to teacher's f() too (etc).  It is amazing what a mess some student's code can be, and you would be surprised how frequently student's code manages to break these regex hacks.  That's what I am trying to avoid!

Comment: Have you tried to make the symbols weak? i.e `objcopy -W _z1fi student.o` and `objcopy -N main student.o` and `objcopy -W _z1gi teacher.o`

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat violates your requirements, but I would suggest you to change the expected form of student's code. Do not require them to code `main`, or ask then to code `main` in a separate compilation unit, or just ask them to rename their `main` to say `main_` before submission. Or just add `#define main main_` to the top of student's code after the submission before the compilation; for simple tasks this will be enough.

After that, you do not need to strip anything from compiled code. Just place all *your* functions to `namespace teacher`, write your own `main` that will do all needed work, and link all code together. Change and recompile your code to call `teacher::f` for your function, or `::f` for the student's function.

Comment: Hi Petr, Once again, this is indeed part of the bodged hacked "solution" that I currently employ and am trying to improve.  I am fine with the macro #define hack for main. The main problem is that I have to modify the student code throughout and replace all student function calls to f() or g() or any other of the functions in the assessed set to teacher::f() and teacher::g() etc.  This is a bit messy but can (and does) break badly if students use unexpected syntax or use multiple-function solutions to problems when I expect only one function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only possible solution is to separate it to two files:

1st file should be common for teacher and student and may contain both `main` and `f` + forward declaration for `g`:

#### common file: (common.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;
int g(int x) ;

int f(int x) {
  cout << "in teacher-f(" << x << ")" << endl;
  return 46;
}

int main() {
  cout << "in teacher-main()" << endl;
  int x = 2;
  int y = g(x);
  cout << "g(" << x << ") returned " << y <<  endl;  
}
```

2nd file should contain the `g` method (+ forward declaration to `f`):

#### teacher(teacher.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int f(int x);

int g(int x) {
  cout << "in teacher-g(" << x << ")" << endl;
  int y = f(x);
  cout << "f(" << x << ") returned " << y << endl;  
  return 91;  
}
```

#### student (student.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int f(int x);

int g(int x) {
  cout << "in student-g(" << x << ")" << endl;
  int y = f(x);
  cout << "f(" << x << ") returned " << y << endl;  
  return 82;  
}
```

now you can compile teacher from **common.cpp** + **teacher.cpp**

```
g++ -o teacher common.cpp teacher.cpp
```

and student from **common.cpp** + **student.cpp**

```
g++ -o student common.cpp student.cpp
```

The **common.cpp** can be even replaced by a static or shared library and you can add a header instead of the forward declaration of `f`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't meet my requirements nor answer the original question.  It's too difficult to automatically edit foreign and possibly very unpleasant student code to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This was from Lawrence and answers my question.  I can't say about portability etc.

```
g++ -c student.cpp
g++ -c teacher.cpp 
strip -N main student.o
objcopy -W _Z1fi student.o
objcopy -W _Z1gi  teacher.o
g++ -o final teacher.o student.o
./final
```

giving the expected

```
in teacher-main()
in student-g(2)
in teacher-f(2)
f(2) returned 46
g(2) returned 82
```

Thanks!

PS I must have made a typo first time I tried it, or else the order of stripping and weakening is important... my comment to say this objcopy -W idea  doesn't work has now been deleted. The above has been tested a few times now.

Comment: I am also not a linker expert but my understanding is that marking a symbol as 'weak' allows it to be overridden when the linker does symbol resolution. By default, a symbol (function or global / static var) is strong.